# Regexp for nine letters separated by '/'

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that will allow 9 numbers and/or digits to be written in such format: `XXX/XXX/XXX`. However, the amount of them in each can vary, so for example it can be like: `XX/XXXX/XXX` as long as there are max 4 x's.

Tried my best but didn't come up with any solution.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript based solution:

```js
var input = prompt("Enter something");

var isValid = false;

if(/^\d{1,4}\/\d{1,4}\/\d{1,4}$/.test(input) && input.replace(/\//g, "").length == 9) {
  isValid = true;
}

console.log("Valid: ", isValid);
```

> Explanation:

1. `\d` denotes digits.
2. Forward Slash `/` is a special character, hence it needs to be escaped, like `\/`
3. You specify range with `{0,4}`
4. After the pattern is verified, you have to strip out all the `/` from the input, and then compare length with 9

Answer (score 1):

REGEX ONLY

```
(?=\b.{11}\b)[0-9]{1,4}\/[0-9]{1,4}\/[0-9]{1,4}
```

- `(?=\b.{11}\b)` a [positive lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) asserting that you have exactly 11 char (because you have 9 digits and 2 slashes)
- `[0-9]{1,4}` a group of minimum 1 and maximum 4 digits (you can use `\d` instead of `0-9`)
- `\/` a slash escaped

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/YQdQGa/1).

Don't forget to turn the `g` option on, which means that you don't return after the first match.

Comment: Wish I thought of using Regex101 site, good choice, and the Positive Look-ahead, is a better approach.